# Problem to run My "create your first MAUI app"

Tags: c#

When I create the microsoft your first maui app

Under a user limited account with run as administrator the app is run ok
In android emulator but in desktop not run ==> "unable to activate windows store app"

But Under administrator account both are run ok

I prefer using the  user limited account

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please rephrase the content. where is this "Create your first app" from? Is it a custom Maui template?

Comment: its the default net maui app its visual studio generated code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe this will clear my question.

Comment: My question is how to get rid from the error "unable to activate windows store app" ? That I get in running from the user account  for the desktop platform